# Function Design

Tags: c++, python, function

I have an array contanining the position of the different objects in my scene.
To calculate the next movement step

I want to build a function like this:

```
f(x) = 1/(x-pos1)^2 + 1/(x-pos2)^2 + ...
       ^term1         ^term2         ^term_n
```

I don't know how many objects are in my scene so I want to add terms in the function for each objects:

something like:

```
for object in scene:
     add_one_term_to_the_function
return function
```

is there a way to program this?
Preferably in C++ or Python... the only two languages I know...

PS: thx for the answers... but a loop is not what I'm looking for. This would be extremly slow.. because it will calculate the function everytime I call a next event... but I want to calculte it only once... and then pass the events to the calculated "function"...

Comment: Are you talking about constructing functions at runtime?

Comment: Are the terms of the same form for each object added?

Comment: for now yes.... btw... I don't even know if it is possible to do something like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not loop over them?
It's not going to be very much slower than otherwise.

```
def f(x,poslist):
  v = 0
  for pos in poslist:
    v += 1/((x-pos)*(x-pos))
  return v
```

If you really want to do it in python you can do it like this (but I beleive it's going to be very slow)

```
def addterm(f, pos):
  def g(x):
    return f(x)+1/((x-pos)*(x-pos))
  return g

def zero(x): return 0
f = zero
for pos in poslist:
  f=addterm(f, pos)
```

There is no real analogue in C++, because C++ doesn't have closures.
One could simulate it, but it won't be the same, and then you could use a list and a loop instead anyway.

Comment: let's imagine I have 300 objects, I will have to calculate the function 300 times (the way you defined it calls 300 objects so 90'000 calculations...) to calculate the next step. what vivek proposed is more suitable at what I want to do, run the 300 objects construct the function -> pass the object to the newly builded function -> total object call 600.

Comment: No, that isn't what is going to happen. When evaluating his function, it loops by all 300 objects (see the for), which gives 90000 calculations too. You cannot escape doing 90000 calculations. The fastest way of doing those is with a loop, and my first example and @vivek's example should generate about the same code, but mine should be a little faster if you follow the guidelines for writing fast code in python. A loop in C++ should be even faster.

Comment: I thought the function = lambda ecc... would be called once. creating the function said f(x) = 1/...+1/... ecc... than you pass the object in it. Without building the function every time.

Comment: Sure, you only build the function once, but on evaluation you must loop through all the objects all the same. I also build my function only once, and I do it at compile time, which is faster, and creates a faster loop.

Some equivalent transformations that in the end gives almost my function:
function = lambda x : sum([1/(x-obj.pos)**2 for obj in scene])
def function(x): return sum([1/(x-obj.pos)**2 for obj in scene])
def function(x):
  l = [1/(x-obj.pos)**2 for obj in scene]
  v = 0
  for k in l:
    v += k

Comment: thx you for the explanation :D so there is no way to avoid the 90'000 calculations? actually building the function first, should be faster then looping them everytime?

Comment: As I said, there is no way to avoid the 90000 calculations, unless you do some fancy math to remove the dependence on pos, but that doesn't seem possible. And also, building the function is slower than looping over the data in almost all cases. And as I said before, mine and viveks solutions are equivalent. If you need more speed, you can use some tricks to make it faster by doing stuff in parallel for example.

Comment: thx :D but it was to build a new concept not to just gain speed, the vivek question mislead me because of the lambda ;)

Comment: If you want to learn about new concepts like these, I would recomend you learn some functional programming language. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function explained how I made my second version

Answer (score 1):

```
function = lambda x : sum([1/(x-obj.pos)**2 for obj in scene])
```

then you can do

`function(10);function(100);` (and so on)

Comment: and... this is really cool! I think it's the answer... there's a way to do it in C++?

Comment: I think you can do it in c++0x (there is support for lambda functions now)

Comment: Have a look at lambdas in C++ here [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Lambda_functions_and_expressions

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use a container and a loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double f(double x, const std::vector<Position> & positions)
{
  double res = 0;
  for (std::vector<Position>::const_iterator it = positions.begin(); it != positions.end(); ++it)
  {
    res += std::pow(x - *it, -2);
  }
  return res;
}
```

I assume that `Position` is a type that's convertible to a floating point number. You pass a collection of positions as the second argument to the function. `std::vector` is the prototypical container in C++, but there are others to choose from if you have specific needs.

Comment: not really what I'm looking for... this will be extremly slow for what I want to do... because it will calculate the function everytime I call a next event... but I want to calculte it only once...

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you make the question a bit clearer? This can easily be modified into an incremental version.